# mysql insert into copy one record

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to insert a new row in mysql, with just one value copied from the database, and the other values provided directly?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES(val1,val2,(SELECT col3 FROM table WHERE col1=val11 AND col2=val22))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.robsearles.com/2009/04/05/mysql-insert-with-a-select-subquery/

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the values directly within the query you could go with.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) SELECT 'val1', 'val2', col3 FROM table WHERE col1='val11' AND col2='val22';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t1 (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('hello','world',(select col2 from t2 where id=1));
```

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)